# Custom view controller name for reports

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my crash reports (Firebase Crashlytics, etc...) sometimes I'm getting errors and logs which look like this:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
Application tried to present modally a view controller <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x105816800> that is already being presented by <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x104031800>
```

It's quite frustrating to debug. Is there a way to set the meaningful names for my view controllers? Or, at least, a way to get the names of my view controllers locally so I can match them?

Comment: Are you using `AnyView`s in your code?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `AnyView` in a few places, but not at the root level. I don't think it is connected, actually.

Comment: You are likely using the root view controller via UIApplication. That is a terrible practice.

Comment: No, I'm not using the root view controller via UIApplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to set the meaningful names for my view controllers?

No - the view controllers mentioned in the error message are not "your" view controllers. They are created by SwiftUI, as an *implementation detail*, to interop with UIKit.

You can demangle the name using the `swift demangle` command. The mangled name in the error message demangle to

```
SwiftUI.PresentationHostingController<SwiftUI.AnyView>
```

You cannot give them meaningful names, because you cannot override the string representation of `PresentationHostingController`, nor can you change the type argument `AnyView`. SwiftUI erases whatever your view's type is, by wrapping it in `AnyView`.

> a way to get the names of my view controllers locally so I can match them?

If this error came up when you are debugging, you can potentially use the UI debugger in Xcode to find the `PresentationHostingController` with the same memory address.

Otherwise, you cannot. This is just a mangled type name that doesn't tell you anything useful (because `AnyView`).

Comment: Thank you! I was able to find the view controller using UI debugger in Xcode. Not very convenient, but it worked for me.
I'm curious about `AnyView` and meaningful names, is there something wrong in my implementation or is it the way SwiftUI should work? I've checked and couldn't find any explicitly using of `AnyView` in my code which could cause the issue.

Comment: @Stopee Well there probably is something wrong with your implementation, since you are getting an error after all, but it could also be a SwiftUI bug (in the sense that this shouldn't have happened at all, or a different, better error message should be outputted). Without seeing the actual code, I cannot tell.

Comment: @Stopee Whether SwiftUI *should* give you meaningful names is a different story. Other SwiftUI error messages don't mention your views' names, but they do mention the specific built-in view that is problematic. e.g. "Picker: the selection "xxx" is invalid and does not have an associated tag, this will give undefined results."

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! My problem was that I tried to present multiple `.sheet` on the same view. In XCode UI debugger, I see that all my sheets have the same name pattern in their PresentationHostingController. So, it means if there are new errors, I won't get the meaningful name of the view again. I will continue my investigation.